# Move UITableViewCell to top of UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to move a UITableViewCell to the absolute top of the table (`IndexPath 0,0`). I have tried this:

```
let conversation = conversations[indexPath.row]
conversations.remove(at: indexPath.row)
conversations.insert(conversation, at: 0)
conversationsView.moveRow(at: indexPath, to: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0))
```

This does what I want it to do: it moves the cell (currently in `didSelectItemAt` method for test purposes) to the top. However, it doesn't happen visually as I want it to happen.

What happens now is, the cell moves out to the bottom, and gets inserted from the top. What I'd like is some sort of animation that "moves" the cell from the current position (e.g. `IndexPath 4,0` to the new position (`IndexPath 0,0`).

A perfect and accurate example of this is Facebook Messenger. When you are in the overview of all your conversations, and you receive a message in the third conversation, the cell moves "magically" and "visually" as you'd expect. This behavior I want to replicate.

Might be important: I use TextureGroup (AsyncDisplayKit) in my application. But this should behave like `UITableView` under the hood I guess.

Comment: Native `UITableView` does not provide this behaviour. If you really want to replicate it, you'll need to create a twin of your cell (the full clone), add it on top of the `UITableView`, animate it, and then remove it.

Comment: Are you sure? Is that how Messenger does it? Seems a bit complex to perform a “basic” animation imo

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I’d create a snapshot of the cell and animate it accordingly? Seems like I could have issues if only part of the cell is visible, no?

Comment: Why do you think that Messenger is using some native `UITableView` reordering behaviour? I did not write the "snapshot" word in my comment. The twin is literally a twin, you create a cell as `UITableViewCell(...)`, then configure it in the same way as your in-table-view-cell, with `cellforRow(at:)` logic. And then animate it as a regular UIView.

Comment: Went with the snapshot approach, because a copy of the cell could be corrupted when the cell is being reused while updating. Snapshot works fine along some other transitioning, like showing a white overlay during the transition and pushing the new message in from the top. Cheers for the suggestion!